# ansi-term won't find file under current directory?

Tags: emacs, ansi-term

It's a very strange problem. I think it must caused my incorrect configuration of `ansi-term`, but i still can't find out where it is.

The issue is: when i in `ansi-term` and press `M-x find-file`, the prompt isn't current directory but the path i entered in my previous find file action. So when i change directory, it still display the same directory. So i have to enter the current directory every time. But it works very well in `M-x shell` and `M-x eshell`

Comment: It works correctly on my system (i.e.  `find-file` defaults to the shell's current working directory). I'm using Emacs23.2.1 (Debian flavour) and bash. I suspect this has to do with the shell rather than Emacs itself. Which shell are you using?

Comment: Related question: [How can I have term.el (ansi-term) track directories if using anyhting other than bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3508387/1225607)

Comment: @Francesco Thanks, it works very well. I think this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the same thing happen when you start Emacs without your init file, i.e., `emacs -Q`?  If so, that's the designed behavior or (especially if you use a development snapshot) perhaps an Emacs bug.

If not, then bisect your init file recursively to find out which part of it causes this behavior.  To do that, use, e.g., command `comment-region` (see prefix arg in doc) to comment and uncomment a block of text.  Comment out 1/2 of your init file, then 3/4, then 7/8,...,
each time testing whether the uncommented portion causes or removes the problematic behavior.  You will very quickly identify what causes the behavior.

Comment: Yes, it's a good point. But after i launch without init file, i still got the same result.

Comment: In that case, either accept that it is by design or file an enhancement request or bug report.  You do either of those things with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Give a recipe to reproduce the problem from `emacs -Q` in the report, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Because the path of emacs is different from that of term, it can only be changed by use the emacs command "cd".

So to solve this problem, I add the following code to my emacs configure file. The method is

1. find the pid of current term
2. find current working directory(cwd) of this pid.

I use multi-term, I think the method will be similar on ansi-term.

```
(defadvice term-send-input (after update-cwd)
(let* ((pid (process-id (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
     (cwd (shell-command-to-string
           (format "lsof -p %d -Fn | awk 'NR==2{print}' | sed \"s/n\\//\\//\" |  tr -d '\n'" pid))))
(cd cwd)
(message (concat "change emacs path to: " cwd))))
(ad-activate 'term-send-input)
```

Then you can bound the key of term-send-input to `<enter>`. When you press `<enter>` in term, the emacs will change to the same path with the current path of term.

BTW, I use Mac Os. If you are on Linux, you can use the following code to find cwd.

```
(cwd (file-truename (format "/proc/%d/cwd" pid)))
```